How does this article deduce "the cross product is invariant under proper rotations"?
How does this formulae relate to the statement above it? This is from Cross Product on Wikipedia. I can't see how the result is easily deduced from the statement.

From the geometrical definition, the cross product is invariant under proper rotations about the axis defined by $\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}$.
$$(R\mathbf{a}) \times (R\mathbf{b}) = R(\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}),\text{where $R$ is a rotation matrix with $\det(R) = 1$.}$$


Are you familiar with group actions?

@coiso I had an introduction to groups, rings, fields and their morphisms in my first Algebra couse, but I don't know what "group actions" mean

“Invariant” would mean that $(R\mathbf{a}) \times (R\mathbf{b}) = \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}$. Or perhaps that $R(\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}) = \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}$. They mean that rotations distribute over cross products.

The formula is actually a stronger statement.
It says that if $\mathbf c$ is the cross product of $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$,
you can rotate all three vectors by the same rotation about any axis
and after rotation the first vector will still be the cross product of the other two.
That is, start with $\mathbf a \times \mathbf b = \mathbf c$;
rotate all three vectors by the same rotation,
\begin{align}
\mathbf a &\mapsto \mathbf a' = R \mathbf a, \\
\mathbf b &\mapsto \mathbf b' = R \mathbf b, \\
\mathbf c &\mapsto \mathbf c' = R \mathbf c; \\
\end{align}
and you end up with $\mathbf a' \times \mathbf b' = \mathbf c'$.
Note that if this were not true, we could not make the geometric interpretation of the cross product that we do, since that interpretation is independent of the coordinate frame and works the same under any rotation.
The statement that the cross product is invariant under proper rotations
about the axis defined by $\mathbf a \times \mathbf b$ is a corollary of the formula.
In the case where $R$ is a rotation about the axis defined by
$\mathbf a \times \mathbf b$,
$R(\mathbf a \times \mathbf b) = \mathbf a \times \mathbf b$
(a vector rotated about itself is the same vector)
and therefore you can rotate $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ about that axis as much as you like with no effect on $\mathbf a \times \mathbf b$.

1- by geometric interpretation you mean right-hand rule ? I don't 100% understand linear transformations as a change of basis tbh.
2- from now I should understand these statements like this? cuz from the phrase I thought the formulae is exactly the statement written as an equation.


You can think of the rotation as a change of basis, but you don't need to: if you rotate your right hand it's still a right hand, and rotating a figure with certain angles between the vectors gives you a figure with the same angles between the vectors. 2. Wikipedia gets edited and re-edited and re-edited and should never be taken as a perfect statement of anything. Don't try to parse it too closely.


I mean why state $R(a\times b)=a\times b$ in words then write formula $Ra\times Rb=R(a\times b)$ what does $Ra\times Rb$ have to do with any of the first statement?

thank you! my problem is that I tried to parse it like an analysis book or stackexchange answer. Also yeah, rotating a right hand it stays like a right hand, now that I think about it that's why there is a right hand rule to begin with hhh!

As it happens, in one of the edits on Jan 21, 2015 someone decided to insert the formula. Before then, the article just described the invariant and then said "More generally" followed by an even more general formula. But they inserted a formula for a general rotation rather than a rotation about the axis of $\mathbf a\times\mathbf b$. Huh! See https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cross_product&diff=643548089&oldid=643449537
